# Setup Nginx as a proxy to Nodejs and Django

Tags: node.js, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a web project locally in my machine. I am using a js framework for my front end, and django for the back end that provides an API to communicate to the front end app. Node app is running on port 3000, and django is running on port 8000. Both are working fine on my local machine. Now I would like to deploy it for production and would like to setup Nginx for the reverse proxy. In the past I have setup nginx as reverse proxy only for the django website, something like this:

```
server {
    server_name someproject.com www.someproject.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/someproject/static_cdn/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/someproject/someproject.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/someproject.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/someproject.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.someproject.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = someproject.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name someproject.com www.someproject.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

But, how can I configure and secure Nginx with ssl as the reverse proxy for both the node server as the front-end running on port 3000, and Django as its backend running on port 8000. I hope I was clear, and if not please ask. Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought about dockerizing your applications? With docker, you can use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) that can automatically use nginx to serve your applications based on a few environment vars. There is also an automatic add-on to provide let's encrypt certificates.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to structure this, depending on how you expect your node app to communicate with your django app.  the easiest way is to divide your nginx configuration with configurations for *two* separate server_name configs.  e.g., www.someproject.com => node and api.someproject.com for django:

```
server {
    server_name www.someproject.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/someproject/static_cdn/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/someproject.node/someproject.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.someproject.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.someproject.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name api.someproject.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/someproject.django/someproject.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.someproject.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.someproject.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    # redirect someproject.com => www.someproject.com
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name someproject.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://www.someproject.com$request_uri;
    }
}    

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.someproject.com api.someproject.com;
    # redirect http => https
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, suppose I am hosting on a VPS (digital ocean), I will have to create an A record for the sub domain on my VPS right? Or is it not required?

Comment: Yes, you would need either an A or a CNAME.  You could also have this to serve the api from the /api route or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to actually put two apps under two different path.

```
location /{
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/someproject/django.sock;
}

location /node {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/someproject/node.sock;
}
```

In this case, you need to adjust node web app to take into account the path is now prefixed with `node`.

Comment: And you need to make sure you don't have `/node` in your urls configuration in django.